# Making a Discord bot that kicks a random person from a group call

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a Discord bot that will randomly kick a member of a voice chat when someone sends the message `remove`. The code below randomly selects a person out of an array of usernames but after this I can't find a way to remove them for a group chat.

```
if(message.content == "remove"){
    let check = 0;
    let user;
    while(check == 0){  
        try{ 
            const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
            user = client.users.cache.find(user => user.username === peope[0]);
            console.log(user.username);
            check = 1;
        }
        catch{

        }
    }
    user.kick;
}
```

Comment: where is `peope` defined? Also you are trying to fetch a user from the whole cache of your bot, and not just the call.

Comment: people is an array of strings defined earlier globally I would like to get just the people in the call but at the moment it is just a list of the most common people